# I can't use the same parameter in a method. CS0136

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I can't use the same parameter in the method DetermineCarValue

```
public static decimal DetermineCarValue(Car carValue)
        {
            decimal carValue = 100.0M;
            return carValue;
        }
```

When I type the carValue parameter I get this error

```
CS0136  A local or parameter named 'carValue' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter
```

Comment: Isn't the error obvious?

Comment: You have `carValue` as both a parameter of type `Car`, and a local of type `decimal`. You'll have to pick a different name for one of the two.

Comment: Are you saying that you didn't even READ the error message before pasting it into the question box?

Comment: Why is this even a question?

Comment: I read the error message but didn't understand it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You answered your own question:

> I can't use the same parameter in the method DetermineCarValue

rename the local method variable `carValue` to something else.

You have two variables with the same name, one passed to the method and one you declared inside the method.

```
public static decimal DetermineCarValue(Car carValue)
{
     decimal carValue = 100.0M;
     return carValue; // which carValue ? of type Car or decimal ? Confusing
}
```

I don't really know what this method is supposed to do, but if you meant to update some property on the `Car` object then you can do this:

```
public static decimal DetermineCarValue(Car car)
{
    // suppose you have property called Value in your Car class
    car.Value = 100.0M;
    return car.Value;
}
```

Conclusion:

You **can't** declare a method variable with the same name as a method parameter. More precisely, you can't have two identifiers with the same name within the same scope.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to paraphrase the compiler error you got in case it is not obvious to you.

The identifier you used for the Car typed parameter is the same as the one you used for the decimal typed variable that you declared in the same scope, the scope being restricted to your method. This induces ambiguity and makes it impossible for the compiler to determine which variable you are referring to. To fix this problem rename either the parameter or the defined variable.

If you wanted to overload the variable, carValue, please note that it is simply not supported.